# Using windows login in a Stored Procedure to pull data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm using windows login to find the department a user belongs to but based on how the windows login is domain_name\first_name.last_name; the stored procedure is not pulling the data correctly. The domain part is not stored in the employee database.

Stored Procedure

```
@name varchar
     select department from employee where  where  lower(emp_firstname) + '.' + lower(emp_lastname)=@name
```

Was trying to put the domain name in '' but that didn't work

Comment: Just a thought ... you assume the domain name will be always first_name.last_name, but with namesakes the domain administrator will assign different login names. Wouldn't be better to add "login name" to your database?

Comment: ... lower() is probably not necessary because the default collation is not  case sensitive. On the other hand, if you have a case sensitive collation, you may want to use lower(@name) as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* what you're trying to say here, is you're trying to match `Joe.Bloggs` against `Domain/Joe.Bloggs`, correct?

Firstly, your query has `where` in it twice, so the syntax is wrong. Secondly, you'll need to strip the first part of the name out.

This should do what you're after, if my quess is correct:

```
CREATE TABLE #User (Firstname varchar(10), Surname varchar(10));

INSERT INTO #User
VALUES ('Joe','Bloggs');
GO

DECLARE @User varchar(30) = 'YourDomain\Joe.Bloggs';

SELECT *
FROM #User
WHERE Firstname + '.' + Surname = STUFF(@User, 1, CHARINDEX('\',@user),'');
GO

DROP TABLE #User;
```

Comment: so you set the user 'YourDomain\Joe.Bloggs'

Comment: @KejaunLeslie huh?

Comment: how do I ensure that this query would match what ever is stored in this System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: I don't know much about web applications I'm afraid, and I don't know what the value of that would be.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name nvarchar(128) = (SELECT Login_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions 
where session_Id = @@SPID);
SET @name = (substring(@name, charindex('\', @name) + 1, 128))
select department 
from employee 
where lower(emp_firstname) + '.' + lower(emp_lastname)
      = @name;
```

If the name is obtained from the current session, you can use:

```
select department 
from employee 
where lower(emp_firstname) + '.' + lower(emp_lastname)
      = 
      (SELECT nt_user_name from sys.dm_exec_sessions where session_Id = @@SPID)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first extract first and last name from login and then filter your table by these values:

```
declare @full_name sysname = substring(system_user, charindex('\', system_user) + 1, len(system_user));
declare @last_name sysname = parsename(@full_name, 1); select @last_name;
declare @first_name sysname = parsename(@full_name, 2); select @first_name;

select department 
from employee 
where  emp_firstname = @first_name
       and emp_lastname = @last_name;
```